# Jenkins Pipeline (Workflow) Stage View disappears

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-workflow

I have the problem, that in some Jenkins Pipeline projects the Stage View becomes invisible.

Usually, you can see the stage view between "Recent Changes" and "Permalinks". After some runs of a project, the Stage View disappears. If I clone the project, then the view is visible in the clone, but not in the original project.

It's a workaround to clone the project, but not a good one because I cannot replace the job every week.

Has someone seen that problem before and has an idea, how to fix that?

The stage view div, is on the job overview page, but it's not visible:

```html
<div class="cbwf-stage-view">
    <div class="cbwf-widget cbwf-controller-applied pipeline-staged" objecturl="/user/myname/my-views/view/MaintainedByMe/job/Category/job/ProjectName/" fragcaption="Stage View" cbwf-controller="pipeline-staged"></div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/adjuncts/ee6b655e/org/jenkinsci/pipeline/stageview_adjunct.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="/adjuncts/ee6b655e/org/jenkinsci/pipeline/stageview_adjunct.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

My Jenkinsfile:

```groovy
def sonarHostUrl = 'http://sonar.host.url:1234'

node('Build') {
    echo "enforce a clear workspace:" // because there were some other problems
    deleteDir()

    stage('Checkout') {
        checkoutFromSVN()
    }
    stage('Compile') {
        mvn 'clean compile test-compile'
    }
    stage('Unit Tests') {
        mvn '-B org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent test'
        step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])
    }
    stage('Deploy to Nexus') {
        mvn 'install deploy -DskipTests'
        archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/project-name*.jar', onlyIfSuccessful: false
    }
    stage('Local Integration Tests') {
        mvn '-B org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent-integration failsafe:integration-test failsafe:verify'
        step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/failsafe-reports/TEST-*.xml'])
    }
    stage('Sonar'){
        mvn "org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=$sonarHostUrl"
    }
}
stage('Deploy to DEV') {
    build 'JobThatDeploysTheApplicationToDevEnv'
}
stage('Functional Tests') {
    build job: 'JobWithSoapUITests', parameters: [string(name: 'TESTENVIRONMENT', value: 'DEV')]
}

def checkoutFromSVN(){
    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
            excludedCommitMessages: '.*\\[maven-release-plugin\\].*',
            locations: [[credentialsId: 'a1a2b3c4-1234-ab1d-b56c-0ac4bff23a6c', 
                       depthOption: 'infinity', 
                       ignoreExternalsOption: true, 
                       excludedRegions: 'Jenkinsfile',
                       local: 'project-dir', 
                       remote: 'https://url.to/project-dir']], 
            workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])
}

def mvn(String args) {
    def mvnCmd = "${tool name: 'Maven 3.3.9', type: 'hudson.tasks.Maven$MavenInstallation'}/bin/mvn"

    wrap([$class: 'ConfigFileBuildWrapper', 
          managedFiles: [[
                    fileId: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.maven.GlobalMavenSettingsConfig1234567', 
                    targetLocation: '', // temporary file
                    variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS']]]) {
        bat "${mvnCmd} -s ${env.MAVEN_SETTINGS} ${args} -f project-dir/pom.xml"
    }
}
```

My Job configuration exported as XML:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<flow-definition plugin="workflow-job@2.9">
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
      <strategy class="hudson.tasks.LogRotator">
        <daysToKeep>-1</daysToKeep>
        <numToKeep>10</numToKeep>
        <artifactDaysToKeep>-1</artifactDaysToKeep>
        <artifactNumToKeep>-1</artifactNumToKeep>
      </strategy>
    </jenkins.model.BuildDiscarderProperty>
    <org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty>
      <triggers>
        <hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
          <spec>H H * * *</spec>
        </hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
        <hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
          <spec>H/10 7-18 * * *</spec>
          <ignorePostCommitHooks>false</ignorePostCommitHooks>
        </hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger>
      </triggers>
    </org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.properties.PipelineTriggersJobProperty>
  </properties>
  <definition class="org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition" plugin="workflow-cps@2.23">
    <scm class="hudson.scm.SubversionSCM" plugin="subversion@2.6">
      <locations>
        <hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation>
          <remote>https://url.to/project-dir</remote>
          <credentialsId>a1a2b3c4-1234-ab1d-b56c-0ac4bff23a6c</credentialsId>
          <local>.</local>
          <depthOption>infinity</depthOption>
          <ignoreExternalsOption>true</ignoreExternalsOption>
        </hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation>
      </locations>
      <excludedRegions></excludedRegions>
      <includedRegions>Jenkinsfile</includedRegions>
      <excludedUsers></excludedUsers>
      <excludedRevprop></excludedRevprop>
      <excludedCommitMessages></excludedCommitMessages>
      <workspaceUpdater class="hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateWithRevertUpdater"/>
      <ignoreDirPropChanges>false</ignoreDirPropChanges>
      <filterChangelog>false</filterChangelog>
    </scm>
    <scriptPath>Jenkinsfile</scriptPath>
  </definition>
  <triggers/>
</flow-definition>
```

Comment: You are not alone. I have also seen this problem (and no fix). What "helped" was to purge all old build (there is - of course - a plugin for this).

Comment: Thank's for the reminder to purge old builds. By the way, it works also without a plugin very well, if you change your project to discard old builds (Max # of builds to keep = 1) and undo the changes after one build. However, the problem remains, because I want, that my history remains in the project.

Comment: @SergejWerfel that solution worked for me! Thanks!!

Answer (score 7):

I resolved the issue by manually copying the missing file to the Jenkins server job.

My detail steps:

1. Open pipeline page.
2. Press F12 in Chrome.
3. Check Console for errors.

my error was missing "*\jobs\Dev-Linux-UI\builds\21\workflow\3.xml*", I copied the file from *builds\20\workflow\3.xml*.

It seems that the file is missing during the copy as Jenkins pipeline is not stable enough.

Comment: At least on older versions of Jenkins, this can happen when renaming a Jenkins job. Reverting the name of the job (and making a separate job based on it if needed) should fix it.

Answer (score 3):

When I've see it, it was after restarting jenkins.  If you look in the debugger in a browser, you'll see it's trying to load files that don't exist.  I've filed a bug for this but no response. Please vote for it if it's still something you're seeing: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39143

Comment: Same for me, some `stageview_adjunst.js` missing. Simply restarted Jenkins and it was all fine :)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you may have lost the "pipeline-stage-view" plugin, check if it's installed. In my case that was it.

Comment: This solved my issue, I installed the plugin

Answer (score 0):

I've observed this problem when switching off test trends for the build. Then also "Stage View" disappeared so there must be some conflict between other plugin rather then Jenkins itself.

I also observed that there were no changes on view or build history after that modification so then I simple clone the project and delete the old one. The side effect of this is that the build history has gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a copy of the pipeline without the Stage View - the copy will have it.

- Dashboard > New Item > on the left hand menu
- Give it a name
- Copy from > at the bottom > type name of you pipeline

Enjoy =)

Answer (score 0):

For our Jenkins, it turned out the plugin [Pipeline Stage View](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-stage-view/) had gone missing, or was somehow not installed during a refresh of the Jenkins installation. Ocean Blue was still working, but the plain cell-based view had disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This happened here after one these events

- Changing the pipeline file (Jenkinsfile)
- Changing the job name

However, after a while, the stage view re-appeared. Sometimes it took as long as 30 minutes. The mechanism behind this remains a mistery to me.

So my advice is to be patient before taking any further action.